# How to make a 3D scroll view with NGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I want to make 3D scroll view using NGUI.

Like the YouTube video *[Unity 3D simulates the iPhone scroll screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eOreKhVQeg)*.

How can I make it like this?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Oh... its my mistake i want just tip... not a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the distance of the center image and communication scale!

Comment: I don't think there is enough information for this to be useful for future visitors. Perhaps provide that information, incl. actual code in the question?